# Swift 2 error, converting to JSON

Tags: ios, json, swift2, swifty-json

Ive been having an error with swift 2, its so simple but i cant get it

Here's the code before I started updating it for Swift 2:

```
func updateWeatherInfo(latitude: CLLocationDegrees, longitude: CLLocationDegrees) {
    let url = "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast"
    let params = ["lat":latitude, "lon":longitude]
    println(params)

Alamofire.request(.GET, url, parameters: params)
    .responseJSON { (request, response, json, error) in
        if(error != nil) {
            println("Error: \(error)")
            println(request)
            println(response)
            self.loading.text = "Internet appears down!"
        }
        else {
            println("Success: \(url)")
            println(request)
            var json = JSON(json!)
            self.updateUISuccess(json)
        }
    }
}
```

here's the line throwing error:

```
let json = JSON(json)
```

Here's the whole func after i started

```
    func updateWeatherInfo(latitude: CLLocationDegrees, longitude: CLLocationDegrees) {
        let url = "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast"
        let params = ["lat":latitude, "lon":longitude]
        print(params)

        Alamofire.request(.GET, url, parameters: params)
            .responseJSON { (request, response, json) in

                    print("Success: \(url)")
                    print(request)

                    let json = JSON(json)
                    self.updateUISuccess(json!)

        }
    }
```

updateUISuccess requires a JSON value, but at the moment I have a   (Request )

heres the error description 
[image]

After a suggestion I tried this:

```
.Success(let data):
                    let data_ar = data as! JSON // or NSDictionary or NSString
                    self.updateUISuccess(data_ar)

                case .Failure(let data, let error):
                    print("Request failed with error: \(error)")


                }
```

but the app crashes at  `let data_ar = data as! JSON // or NSDictionary or NSString`

Comment: where does the original `json` come from?

Comment: Can you please remove error from Alamofire?

Comment: I don't quite understand @LGL. If you look at the bottom block of code (what i did after updating to xcode7) i dont have error as a parameter

Answer (score 0):

The variable `json` looks like an enum value. Try this:

```
switch json {
    case .Success(let data):
        let data_ar = data as! NSArray // or NSDictionary or NSString

    case .Failure(let data, let error):
        print("Request failed with error: \(error)")


    }
```

Comment: Does it look like that? It seems to be of type `Rseult<AnyObject>` as the error suggests

Comment: @luk2302 yes you're right. Now I think it looks like an enum :)

Comment: I tried it, and the app crashed when calling an api request, i added the code i tried above